# group and merge xml nodes based on specific child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am fairly new in xslt and have come across a really tricky group merging case. I have a following xml structure:

```
<root>
  <section name="A"> 
    <table name="B">
      <row1/>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section name="A"> 
    <table name="B">
      <row1/>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section name="A"> 
    <table name="B">
      <row1/>
    </table>
    <section name="C"></section>
  </section>
  <section name="A"> 
    <table name="B">
      <row1/>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section name="A"> 
    <table name="B">
      <row1/>
    </table>
  </section>
</root>
```

And I need to transform it in a way such that the code should only merge row1 until it confronts a section which contains a child section with a name of c:

```
<root>
   <section name="A"> 
     <table name="B">
       <row1/>
       <row1/>
     </table>
   </section>
   <section name="A"> 
     <table name="B">
      <row1/>
     </table>
     <section name="C"></section>
   </section>
    <section name="A"> 
     <table name="B">
       <row1/>
       <row1/>
     </table>
   </section>
</root>
```

What I have so far just merges all the rows inside all the sections:

```
<xsl:template match="section[@name='A' and following-sibling::section[@name='A'] ]//table[1]" >
   <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::section[@name='A']/following-sibling::section[@name='A']//table[1]/row1" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="section[ @name='A' and preceding-sibling::section[@name='A'] ]//table[1]" />
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with XSLT 2.0 you should make yourself familiar (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples) with `for-each-group` and its various options like `group-by` and `group-adjacent` and `group-starting/ending-with`, then you can come up with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::section[@name = 'A' and not(section[@name = 'C'])])">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="merge"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row1" mode="merge">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()//row1"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <section name="A">
      <table name="B">
         <row1/>
         <row1/>
      </table>
   </section>
   <section name="A">
      <table name="B">
         <row1/>
      </table>
      <section name="C"/>
   </section>
   <section name="A">
      <table name="B">
         <row1/>
         <row1/>
      </table>
   </section>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks this works like a gem, however I had a small question regarding the for-each loop: Does the loop preserves the order in which it processes the nodes or is it the current-group() function which does that?

Comment: Are you asking about the `for-each-group`? It processes the grouping population selected by `select="*` in population order and forms group after group. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group for the details.